# Unnecessary scrolling of page on iOS

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am Using cordova-2.1.0, JQueryMobile-1.3.0 for iOS app. Some of the pages in my app has very small content still that pages scrolls. I am testing it on iOS 6. How to stop scrolling of the pages having small content. I dont want to use the preventDefault.

Comment: can you show us a screenshot

Comment: Hey I can't post the screenshot it showing me error that you have at least 10 reputations to send image.what to do

Comment: host it outside and give the link here after removing www, http etc

Comment: please check this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/img0276am.jpg/

Comment: can u show some of your code plz. You may be missing a closing `</div>` tag

Comment: <body><div data-role="page" id="menu"><div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h3>Header</h3></div><div data-role="content"><ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenu"><li style="height:50px"><a href="menu1.htm" data-transition="slide"><img src="a.png" class="ui-li-icon"/>Menu1</a></li><li style="height:50px"><a href="menu2.htm" data-transition="slide"><img src="b.jpg" class="ui-li-icon"/>Menu2</a></li></ul></div></div><script charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script><script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script><script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script></body>

Comment: above comment contains code from body only

Comment: remove the custom style `style="height:50px"` and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just looks normal when I tried in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JEqKh/

this is the HTML I used. Try import the libraries in the `<head></head>` tag

```
<div data-role="page" id="menu">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="mainMenu">
            <li style="height:50px"><a href="menu1.htm" data-transition="slide"><img src="a.png" class="ui-li-icon"/>Menu1</a>
            </li>
            <li style="height:50px"><a href="menu2.htm" data-transition="slide"><img src="b.jpg" class="ui-li-icon"/>Menu2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Mayu Thanks and Yes its working fine in browser but not on iPhone or ipod